# Was it the laser-gun weapon Yayoi has in her finger which she uses to kill ghosts?

Tags: dark-gathering

In the series, Yayoi has shown several tools to trap, handle or kill ghosts, like dolls, salt, other ghosts, etc. Recently she has used a laser-like weapon she fires from a glove-like cloth she has in her finger, which she uses to kill ghosts. What is it, and why does this have this power?